# Java SimpleCaptcha: how to make the space between characters a bit larger

Tags: java, captcha, simplecaptcha

I am using a Java's Captcha solution called  [SimpleCaptcha](http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/custom_images.html) for a web application.

I would like to make space between characters a bit larger. How can I do this?

Comment: Putting extra space between the characters would make it easier for OCR to determine the individual characters, thus weakening or defeating the point of a Captcha!

Comment: Hi Andrew, I understand that the risk of having too much space between characters. I am not going to make the space very wide. I just want to be able to adjust it a little. Thanks.

Comment: If you are going to toss the common sense approach out the window, you might as well just draw text to an image using AWT.

Comment: thanks, Andrew. I feel we are talking about two different things. One is the stronger security mechanism, and one about the configureability of a solution. Agree? I need an answer for the latter one.

Comment: *"I need an answer for the latter one."* I already suggested an answer for that in a comment.  *"you might as well just draw text to an image using AWT."*

Comment: @Andrew, I know that using AWT I can create an image with text. The core of my question is to understand whether the particular Java solution I am using offers the capability of adjusting the spacing between text characters and how. The answer should be Yes or No. Do you have any experience with the particular Java solution? Thanks.

Comment: *"Do you have any experience with the particular Java solution?"*  No.

Comment: Did you have a look at/try of [`StretchyWordRenderer`](http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/javadocs/nl/captcha/text/renderer/StretchyWordRenderer.html).  The documentation seems less than optimal.  :(

Comment: Andrew, thanks for finding the info for me. Strangely enough, the package I downloaded for my project does not have this class. I have the package for Java 6.

Comment: Seems the best advice is.  Use a better documented and supported API.  It is called 'Simple' for a reason, & not in a nice way..